# Mention vs use of a word

Tags: quotation-marks, italics

In some cases it's not intuitive whether a word is mentioned or used, so it's difficult determining whether to write the word as normal or to use italics / quotation marks.

Two examples:

When you use the phrase 'is called':

```
The side of the street is called the sidewalk.
The side of the street is called 'the sidewalk.'
```

When you use the phrase 'a.k.a.':

```
[...] trottoir, also knows as sidewalk.
[...] trottoir, also knows as 'sidewalk.'
```

Which versions of these sentences are the correct ones?

Comment: The side of the street is called the sidewalk.

Comment: Whether it’s a use or a mention depends on the intent of the speaker.

Comment: If a word is not part of the native lexicon then it's a good idea to use  inverted commas or italics - to reassure a reader that this word is not idiomatic.  If a word *is* part of the native lexicon, even if it's rarely used or unfamiliar to most, inverted commas are a confusing distraction.

Comment: off-topic: _a.k.a._ stands for _also known as_.

Comment: @Dan That advice is not helpful as you are at best arbitrarily choosing among established conventions.

Comment: The inverted commas are there to aid comprehension, not to satisfy some punctuation czar. In the first pair of examples, "The side of the street is called the 'sidewalk' " emphasises the term and is a perfectly acceptable way to do so. But you are equally free not to do so. However, in the second pair, as _sidewalk_ is not an uncommon term, and with enough emphasis already being provided by the use of the parenthetical, the use of inverted commas could well misdirect a reader. "Is this a rare or colloquial usage over in Austral Zealand?"

Comment: @Lawrence interesting. Could you explain the different intents behind the four sentences?

Comment: @Angelorf By definition, the speaker's intent needs to be explained by the speaker :) . Nevertheless, those with quotes are (syntactically) *mention*s while the others are *use*s.

Comment: @Lawrence I think I get your comment for the second set of sentences, but for the first pair I don't really see how you could intend that in different ways. If you ask me there is only one possible intent and so there is only one correct way of writing the sentence. If you see more than one possible intent for the sentence pair then please elucidate.

Comment: [@Angelorf](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442774/mention-vs-use-of-a-word?noredirect=1#comment1064389_442774) Consider the sentence: "This is Italy". The word *Italy* carries the connotation of everything to do with the country: the place, the people, the food, the culture etc. The 'use' of *sidewalk* in the first pair works analogously. Now consider "Let's call the stations 'Alpha', 'Beta' and 'Gamma'". Here, one is applying a label to something. That's analogous to the 'mention' of *the sidewalk* in the first pair.

Comment: @Lawrence but then "The country is called Italy." would mean that the country is called the place, the food and the culture. I would say that you can only call something by it's name - you cannot call the country the food etc. Calling something something _is_ applying a label to it. So in that sense I think the first is incorrect and the second is correct.

Comment: @Angelorf When you call something X, and X is a proper noun, both use and mention are valid and equivalent. When X isn't a proper noun, there is a difference. E.g. calling a dish of food tasty (use) isn't the same as calling it "tasty" (mention). The *sidewalk* example falls under the not-proper-noun category. It then goes back to the intent of the speaker as to whether this was a *use* or *mention*.

Answer (score 0):

The inverted commas are there to aid comprehension, not to satisfy some punctuation tzar. In the first pair of examples, "The side of the street is called the 'sidewalk' " emphasises the term and is a perfectly acceptable way to do so. But you are equally free not to do so. However, in the second pair, as sidewalk is not an uncommon term, and with enough emphasis already being provided by the use of the parenthetical, the use of inverted commas could well misdirect a reader. "Is this a rare or colloquial usage over in Austral Zealand?"

Comment: The question is not about emphasis, but about quotation. Whether the quotation is done with single apostrophe's, quotation marks or italics is irrelevant to the question.